# File output not coming out as desired - C++

Tags: c++, class, object, input

so I have a class Result, that takes input from a file, and sends the input to another class Unit to read in some details to that unit class, and output it to a file. Everything worked perfectly with all details displayed correctly. Now, I've created another class UnitCoordin (for Unit Coordinator), and this class takes in some additional input from the file, and stores it in an object of itself in the Unit class so that every Unit has a Unit Coordinator.

The program reads correctly, up until it has to read in my Unit Coordinator class. I know this because in my output file, all values for Unit display correctly until it reaches my Unit Coordinator details in which everything is a mess. Perhaps this is a little confusing, but please read my code and files and try to understand. I imagine it is something to do with my input.ignore statements but I've tried moving them around and putting them exactly where it makes sense to but nothing seems to work. Please help

UNIT.cpp input method:

```
void UNIT::SetUnit(istream &input){

  string nam;
  string idd;
  unsigned cred;
  UnitCoordin unitcoordinator1;

  getline(input,nam);
  input.ignore(0, '\n');
  getline(input,idd);
  input.ignore(0, '\n');

  input >> cred;
  input.ignore(0, '\n'); // up until here the values are read correctly

  input >> unitcoordinator1;
  input.ignore(0, '\n');


  SetName(nam);
  SetID(idd);
  SetCredits(cred);
  SetUnitCoordinator(unitcoordinator1);

}
```

UnitCoordin.cpp:

```
void UnitCoordin::SetUnitCoordin(istream &input){

    string name2;
    unsigned roomno2;
    long telephoneno2;
    string email2;

    getline(input,name2);
    input.ignore(0, '\n');
    getline(input,email2);
    input.ignore(0, '\n');

    input >> roomno2 >> telephoneno2;
    input.ignore(0, '\n');


    SetCoordinatorName(name2);
    SetEmail(email2);
    SetRoom(roomno2);
    SetTelephone(telephoneno2);


}
```

Outputfile:

```
Student ID: 102234
Semester:   962
Unit ID:  ICT283
Unit Name: Data Structures and Abstractions
Credits: 3
Unit Coordinator: 
Room Number: 0
Telephone: 7532268
Email: Shri Rai

Marks: 12453264
Date: 7532268  7532624

Unit ID:  
Unit Name: 
Credits: 4293836982
Unit Coordinator: 
Room Number: 0
Telephone: 7532268
Email: 

Marks: 4421840
Date: 7532268  7532624

Unit ID:  
Unit Name: 
Credits: 4293836982
Unit Coordinator: 
Room Number: 0
Telephone: 7532268
Email: 

Marks: 4421840
Date: 7532268  7532624

Number of units = 3
```

As you can see, up until the 'Credits' in my first object output in the output file it has read fine, and afterwards it is all messed up.

Comment: `input.ignore(0, '\n')` ignores zero characters, i.e. it does nothing.

Comment: Don't just 'move things around' to see if it works, you cannot program by fluke. Understand what the problem is and fix it.

Comment: Since you haven't posted your input file it's hard to be certain what the correct code is. But I suggest you spend some time understanding exactly how `getline` and `operator>>` actually work (it's not difficult) and therefore when you might want to use `ignore`. And of course how `ignore` actually works as well.

Comment: I figured ignore would ignore 0 characters, or until newline is found, whichever comes first, so I thought the 0 would make it so that it would ignore until newline character is found. Also, for getline, would it read any characters inluding '@ 'and '.' because that's what the emails are composed of.

Comment: Yes, but zero characters comes first, so it does nothing. To ignore characters until a newline write this `input.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');`, [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/istream/istream/ignore/)

Comment: `getline` reads any characters until the next newline, again [documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/getline/)